# IE 11 not response after a short time when render pdf in iframe

Tags: html, pdf, internet-explorer, adobe-reader

I have two html-pages and local web server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="Cp1251">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="docFrame" width="500px" height="500px"
        src="http://localhost:9080/pass.pdf">
        </iframe>
        <a href="frm2.html">Link to frm2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="Cp1251">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="frm1.html">Link to frm1</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to link  `Link to frm2`, wait about 60 sec, press `Link to frm1`  IE show page `dnserror` and becames unresponsable.
I tried everything my brain can do)

- set no cache resonse headers
- reset IE options to default
- uncheck check appropriate checkboxes in Adobe Reader

with no result

Comment: Did you try it with other browsers?

Comment: Can you please detailed information about the DNS error you got on IE? If possible than try to post the snapshot of an error may help to identify the issue.

Comment: @MrakVladar yes, and it works normally everywhere except IE

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT IE displays page with content than I try to translate: 
Make sure the web address 
Find a page using a search engine
Refresh the page in a few minutes
Check if all network cables are connected
Check if the "in plane" mode is enabled
Make sure the wireless connection is turned on
Check if you can connect to the mobile broadband network
Reboot your router
Fix connection problems

Comment: It can be possible that your internet connection get disconnected frequently or your internet speed is too slow to load the page. in that case this error may occur. Try to check whether your internet connection is working properly or not.